# CakePHP 3.0 dev. Model Save() error?

Tags: php, cakephp

i just try to save input data and in line of save() method show me error , this is my controller register method :

```
public function register() {
    if ($this->Helloworlds->save($this->request->data)) {
        $id = $this->Helloworld->id;
        $this->request->data['Helloworld'] = array_merge($this->request->data['Helloworld'], array('id' => $id));
        $this->Auth->login($this->request->data['Helloworld']);
        return $this->redirect('/helloworld/index');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Sorry no data has saved '));
    }
}
```

and the error :

> Error: Call to a member function isNew() on a non-object   File
>   C:\wamp\www\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php   Line: 1092

i would mention this i'm sure about my model name'helloworlds' 
any idea?

Comment: Are you sure `Helloworlds` is correct? You use the singular in all other commands: `$this->Helloworld->id;`, `$this->request->data['Helloworld']`... CakePHP Naming Convention (at least until 2.x) enforces Model names on Singular, not plural.

Comment: i use Helloworld and non object error , and i tested ``$this->modelClass `` , so ?

Comment: Sorry? I didn't understand what you tried to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at least i find out answer , the true code is :

```
public function register() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {   
      $Helloworld = TableRegistry::get('helloworlds');    $Helloworlds =  $Helloworld->newEntity($this->request->data);   if ($Helloworld->save($Helloworlds)) {
        $id = $this->Helloworld->id;
        $this->request->data['Helloworld'] = array_merge($this->request->data['Helloworld'], array('id' => $id));
        $this->Auth->login($this->request->data['Helloworld']);
        return $this->redirect('/helloworld/index');
    }   else    {       $this->Session->setFlash(__('Sorry no data has saved '));   }   } }
```